# run in production Vue.js on local machine + laravel beckend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, production-environment

I installed laravel an vue.js app on my local machine...
I can run vue.js on dev mod with command

npm run dev

and it works.
But when i build my vue.js app and try to start it, it doesn't work.

I try to access with:

http://localhost:8888/project_name/_frontend-app/dist/index.html

and it is not working.

Can somebody explain how to run vue.js app + laravel app on production

Comment: Are you using laravel as separate application and vuejs as separate application? Is server running on http://localhost:8888 ?

Comment: yes, exactly...
Index page is completely empty, and when I inspect page all assets (js and css) have wrong paths...
And I cannot understand how frontend app interact with backed app if I hit frontend app ?

Comment: You can connect through API

Comment: Thank you...
but my assets are not included properly...
There is blank page on production because all paths for assets are not included properly...(404 error)
on index.html page inside #app folder is comented text "built files will be auto injected", and they are not...

Comment: You need to give more code samples from your work, then only we will inspect it further

Comment: What exactly does `it doesn't work` mean?  Show us your code, show us the error.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)